# Add "Take Photo With Camera" Feature On Website

Tags: php, mobile, cordova, camera, appcelerator

I'm building a web application that requires the user to upload a photo.
The application is built using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript (w/jQuery), and PHP for the backend.
I would like to add, besides the file uploading option, another option for users who use the application on their mobile phone - to upload a picture using the phone's camera.

From browsing a bit, I understood there are 2 approaches to this matter:

1. **The Native Way** - Building an independent application using Andorid's, iOS's and WM's SDK's and then having the user install them.
2. **The Cross-Platform Way** - Using one of the available services, such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/) to "compile" my web application into a variety of mobile phone applications, namely Android and iOS.

Thing is, I'm not interested in creating a separate application, and then having users install it on their phones.

I'm interested in letting a user, who chooses to use the web application on his mobile phone, **the ability** to take a photo using his mobile device.

**How do I go about doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the camera API which lets you either take an image from the device camera or use a stored image. Here's a description on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Camera. It also features a demo there.

Comment: Ok, Thanks For The Answer. However, correct me if I'm mistaken, but this works only for Andoris devices, running Google Chrome/Firefox, as per [link](http://robnyman.github.io/camera-api/). I'll make the fair assessment  most people don't bother with installing 3rd party mobile browsers, and stick with the out-of-the-box one. This solves a small portion, and not the entire problem. Thx for the reference though.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Camera cordova plugin only support for device, not for website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is simple solution
`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`